# Write extension method to retrieve property description using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have following class

```
public class Device
{
    [XmlElement("MobileDeviceType")]
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
}
```

I need extension method called "GetXElementName()" and I need to use the method like below.

```
string propertyDescription = (new Device()).DeviceType.GetXElementName(); // this shoud return "MobileDeviceType"
```

As a example

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetXElementName<T>(this T source)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(source.ToString());
        string desc = prop.Name;
        object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        object attr = attrs[0];
        XmlElementAttribute descAttr = attr as XmlElementAttribute;
        if (descAttr != null)
        {
            desc = descAttr.ElementName;
        }

        return desc;
    }
}
```

Can I know how should I modify the method body to use the "GetXElementName()" method to use like I explained above.

Comment: Well, doesn´t it work as expected? What error do you get?

Comment: You may want to loop through all attributes, to be safe, rather than just taking the first one, and when you find one that is an `XmlElementAttribute` you just return the `ElementName`.

Comment: Btw.: to get a property via reflection you will need the properties **name**, not its string-represenation. Thus `source.ToString` doesn´t make much sense. In your case `source.ToString` will just return whatever the **value** of `DeviceType` in your `Device` is, not just `"DeviceType"`. What exactly should your method actually do?

Comment: @HimBromBeere,
Method should return property XElement description. In this case the method should return "MobileDeviceType"

Comment: It won't work anyway; `DeviceType.GetXElementName()` will attempt to run this function _on the result from the getter of that property_, not on the property itself. You need a call like `new Device()).GetXElementName("DeviceType");`.

Comment: @Nyerguds or, like in my answer, through expressions

Comment: @T-moty Oh, that's interesting. Didn't know you could do stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **Expressions** to achieve that, because you need to know the member, not the value.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetXmlElementName<T, TProperty>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var xmlElementAttribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementAttribute>();
        if (xmlElementAttribute == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return xmlElementAttribute.ElementName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Test")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

new MyClass().GetXmlElementName(x => x.MyProperty) // output "Test"
```

**EDIT: another version, without an object instance (see [Nyerguds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395685/nyerguds) comment)**

I guess the most elegant way is make a generic class, with a generic method, so you can call it by specify only the `T` type parameter (`TProperty` is taken implicitly).

```
public class GetXmlElementName<T>
{
    public static string From<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var xmlElementAttribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementAttribute>();
        if (xmlElementAttribute == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return xmlElementAttribute.ElementName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GetXmlElementName<MyClass>.From(x => x.MyProperty) // output "Test"
```

Comment: This version allow strong typed properties. I prefer this approach.

Comment: Clearly the superior answer, yes. Bravo. For people still stuck in v3.5, there's only 'GetCustomAttributes', plural, and it gets the type to find as argument, but besides needing an array length check instead of a null check, it works exactly the same.

Comment: The only nitpick I have is that it still requires the dummy object... is there a way to do this without it? (yes, I know it's asked this way, but still, it's rather silly)

Comment: Seems it _can_ be done without, by changing the signature to `GetXmlElementName<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> expression)` and the call to `GetXmlElementName<MyClass>(x => x.MyProperty);`

Comment: @Nyerguds in C# you need to specify _all_ type arguments, or none of them (if they are implicitly taken).
I updated my answer with an elegant solution (imho).

Comment: Well, using `Object` solved that in my example, but yes, you can also embed it in a helper class that takes the explicit generic types. In fact, I experimented a bit with this and ended up with a completely generic attribute-property fetching system where you even give which attribute class and which property from it to fetch: `public static class PropertyCustomAttributeUtil<T, TAttr> where TAttr : Attribute` -> `public static TRes GetValue<TProp, TRes>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression, Expression<Func<TAttr, TRes>> attrExpression)`. This stuff is fun :)

Comment: Oh, that last param of course doesn't need to be an `Expression`... just `Func<TAttr, TRes>` is enough.